# Angular router click scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular project, I have a click that is storing some info and then using the `router.navigate` function to move to a new page. Like

```
  localStorage.setItem('data', stringify(data));
  localStorage.setItem('search', stringify(this.search));
  this.router.navigate(['/somewhere/someplace/search']);
```

This is working perfectly, however when going to the new page if you are scrolled to the bottom of the page the new page stays at the bottom of page. Is there a way to move/scroll it to the top of the page so the user doesn't have to scroll up to see the content?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$window.scrollTo(x, y);` to set the scroll of your page to x and y values corresponding to your page.

Giving 0 to both means at the top-left of page(beginning of page) so in your case i would do `$window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

also if you want it to focus on an element instead of just the scrolling to top do the following `$window.scrollTo(0, angular.element('myelement').offsetTop);`

in your case it would be like this

```
 localStorage.setItem('data', stringify(data));
  localStorage.setItem('search', stringify(this.search));
  this.router.navigate(['/somewhere/someplace/search']);
  $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: Would I do that after routing to the page? I tried something similar with "window" but I couldn't get it to work within angular

Comment: It' won't let me add $window, it makes me change it to Window. and then it throws this error message "Property 'scrollTo' does not exist on type '{ new (): Window; prototype: Window; }'."

Comment: You have to inject the $window ofcourse like this ``angular.module('myApp', [])

 .config(function ($windowProvider) {
   var $window = $windowProvider.$get();
   console.log($window);
 })``